# Confusing behaviour of Cheerio (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-selectors, request, cheerio

I was recently introduced to Node.js.

I am trying to scrape the url="http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=great+gatsby" using Node.js, cheerio and request, to find the links to 20 most relevant results.

Now, if I search for `"id='fk-header'"`, I get an html output.
However, if I search for `"id='login-signup-newDialog'"`, I get a NULL output.

Both these occur only once in the web page's html.

Similarly, if I use this:

```
var x=$("div[class='unit search-bar-submit-wrap size1of6']");
```

I get output as expected. But if I use:

```
var x=$("div[class='aff-tracker fk-hidden']");
```

The output is again NULL.
Both these class names occur only once.

I am unable to understand this behavior of cheerio where I can find some elements, but not others.

Here is the basic code I am using:

```
var request = require("request"),
cheerio = require("cheerio"),
url = "http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=great+gatsby";

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        // console.log(body);
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var x=$("div[id='fk-header']");

        console.log(x.html());
    } else {
        console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
    }
});
```

Also, I understand that to get all the 20 links, I will need to find all occurrences of class-"product-unit unit-4 browse-product new-design ", and then find the href attribute of child of its child.
But I am unable to find any occurrence of this class,(not even the first occurrence).

Could someone please explain why am I getting such a confusing behavior on using cheerio?

Comment: Likely because items are asynchronously loaded. try using `setTimeout` and let them get rendered

Comment: Using `setTimeout` for 5000, I still get null output in the given cases.

Comment: I don't think I am missing any classes for these elements. This behavior is just weird.

Comment: Too old to help, but the data is probably injected by JS and isn't in the static HTML.